# How to remove a functional dependancy from a state dispatch update

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

The issue I'm facing is that I have an item in state called `foo` and then I have a `useCallBack` that fires a series of dispatches and references the state item `foo`.

I'm also firing a `UseEffect` on page load to handle any changes from the database.

The issue I'm having is as follows

1. The page loads
2. `useEffect` triggers and loads data from server
3. The useEffect runs it's code and if required calls the `useCallBack` which is a dependancy of the `useEffect`
4. The `useCallback` fires a series of dispatches that update `foo`
5. State Item `foo` has changed
6. The `useCallback` is watching `foo` and updates
7. The `useEffect` is watching the `useCallback` and as it has changed it runs again
8. Steps **3-7** repeat infinitely

An example in code format:

```
const { state, dispatch } = React.useContext(AppContext};
const { foo } = state;

const handleBar = React.useCallBack((bar: IBarType) => {
    const bar_exists = _.find(foo, {id: bar.id});
    if (bar){
        dispatch({ type: 'rainbows', payload: bar });
    } else {
        dispatch({ type: 'clouds', payload: bar });
    }
}, [foo]}

React.useEffect(() => {
    serverFunction...
    if (x){
       handleBar(data)
    }
}, [handleBar]}
```

My assumption is that the dependancy on `foo` within the `handleBar` callback is causing the infinite loop, I know you can remove the dependancy from a reactHook by using something like `setState(bar => bar ...)`.

However, I Just can't seem to apply the same rules to the `handleBar` function.

I've tried `const bar_exists = _.find(foo: as IFooType => foo, { id: bar.id});` to no luck.

Comment: Is it possible for you to move the callback function inside of the `useEffect` handler?

Comment: @JoshWilson moving the code inside the useCallback invokes the same infinite loop as it's `foo` that's causing the rerunning of the side-effect

Comment: If you have a loop like `foo updates => dispatch change to foo => foo updates ...`, you need to make sure there is a condition where no dispatch is made. It seems like you are performing a dispatch unconditionally.

Comment: Is the second `useCallback` in your code example actually `useEffect`?

Comment: @Hangindev yes good catch, updated +1